# Download PDF DomPDF Laravel Nova 4

Tags: laravel-nova, laravel-dompdf, barryvdh

The Laravel Nova 4 documentation says that to implement a download action I should do it like this:

```
return Action::downloadUrl('https://example.com/invoice.pdf', 'Invoice.pdf');
```

But it doesn't work.

I am generating through the Barryvdh\DomPDF package a PDF with a blade template. The only way I have managed to get it to work is to add this route to web.php

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', function ($file) {
$path = storage_path("app/public/pdf/{$file}");
if (!File::exists($path)) {
abort(404);
}
$file = File::get($path);
$type = File::mimeType($path);
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);
return $response;
})->name('download');
```

And then in action:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models).
{
$troncopdf = Pdf::loadView('troncopdf', compact('models'));
$fileName = 'troncopdf.pdf';
$path = "public/pdf/{$fileName}";
Storage::put($path, $troncopdf->output());
return Action::redirect(route('download', $fileName));
}
```

The problem is that instead of downloading it, it opens it in the browser and I would like it to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in route:

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', function ($file) {
    $path = storage_path("app/public/pdf/{$file}");
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $fileContent = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);
    $fileName = basename($path);

    $response = Response::make($fileContent, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    // Usa $fileName en lugar de $file
    $response->header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename={$fileName}");

    return $response;
})->name('download');
```